# vi: what is verbose mode and when/how do I use it?

Tags: vim, vi

Sometimes When I'm using vi I accidentally hit `caps lock` when I'm in `command mode`. This apparently puts vi into `verbose mode` which I'm having trouble finding documentation about how to use. How and when should I use `verbose mode`?

Comment: +1 for another vi "I accidentally hit X while Y, and it activated another damn mode. What's this one, then?" story :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[snip]
* Start Vim in verbose mode: vim -V. (Describes each file being sourced).
```

or from the manual page:

```
[snip]
When 'verbose' is non-zero messages are printed (for debugging, to stderr).
```